# If $0 \leq f_n(x)\leq g_n(x)$ and $\Sigma_{n=1}^{\infty}g(n)$ converges uniformly, then $\Sigma_{n=1}^{\infty}f(n)$ converges uniformly?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, uniform-convergence

I am pretty sure this has to be true. I go back to basic sequence and series, if $0 \leq (a_k) \leq (b_k)$, I know that if  $\Sigma_{k=1}^{\infty}(b_k)$ converges, then  $\Sigma_{k=1}^{\infty}(a_k)$ converges.

Then I just need to apply the Weierstrass M-test to the series of functions, right?

Thanks!

Comment: $$\left| \sum_{k=1}^\infty f_k(x)-  \sum_{k=1}^n f_k(x) \right|\leq \sum_{k=n+1}^\infty |f_k(x)|\leq \sum_{k=n+1}^\infty g_k(x)$$ So $0 \leq |f_n(x)|\leq g_n(x)$ is enough actually.

Comment: Since those series are just numerical series, it doesn't really make sense to talk about their uniform convergence. Perhaps you misstated the problem.

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean $\sum f_n$ and $\sum g_n$ in the question?

Comment: @zhw, a series of functions can converge uniformly, I did not misstate anything. I was just wondering if they behave more or less the same way numerical series do.

Comment: You definitely misstated something. You surely do not mean $g(n)$ because it is not defined. However, LeGrandDODM gave you the answer.

Comment: If $g_n$ converges uniformly to $0$. .Otherwise it's not a valid inference.